# Clear a vector of derived classes using a function with a vector of class as argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class `Animal`, with two derived classes `Cat` and `Dog` respectively.
I also have a class `House` which contains two lists as attributes: a list of every cat in the house ( `std::vector<Cat*>` ), and a list of every dog ( `vector<Dog*>`).

My goal is to code a function in House which clears a list of animals ( `void House::clearList( std::vector<Animal*> )` ). I'd like to avoid duplicating code as much as possible. Hence, creating one function for both list would be optimal.

I'd like to call this function in the destructor of `House`:

```
class Animal{};

class Dog : public Animal{};
class Cat : public Animal{};

class House{
    private :
        std::vector<Dog*> Dogs;
        std::vector<Cat*> Cats;
    public :
       ~House(){
            clearList(dogs);
            clearList(cats);
       }
       clearList(std::vector<Animal*> animals){
            for (auto& animal : animals){
                 animal=nullptr;
                 delete animal;
            }
       }
};
```

The compiler displays :

> error: no matching function for call to '`House::clearList(std::vector<Cat*>&)`'
>       note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '`std::vector<Cat*>`' to '`std::vector<Animal*>`'

I can't use `shared_ptr` nor `unique_ptr` in my code.

How can I use polymorphism to solve this?

Comment: `animal=nullptr; delete animal;` is probably not going to work like you think it will.

Comment: Think on what can happen if you `delete` all of the `dogs` if `dogs` and `animals` share pointers to instances.

Comment: *"I can't use shared_ptr nor unique_ptr in my code."* Write your own smart pointer then.

Comment: Passing a vector to a function by value could leave the caller confused, since the actual vector passed will not be changed, but the pointers it contains will be deleted.

Comment: Also, having gone to the trouble of deriving things from Animal, why do you have separate vectors for cats and dogs?

Comment: Animal does not have a virtual destructor.  Things will not end well.

Comment: This seems the wrong way round: `animal=nullptr; delete animal;`

Comment: C++ doesn't have [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, but this is just a dummy code to represent a bigger project. I couldn't upload 20 files worth of code in one question ^^. I even had to change the names to make it sound a bit more logical.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism isn't what you are looking for.  You can use a template instead, eg:

```
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual ~Animal(){}
};

class Dog : public Animal{};
class Cat : public Animal{};

class House{
    private :
        std::vector<Dog*> Dogs;
        std::vector<Cat*> Cats;

        template<typename T>
        void clearList(std::vector<T*> &animals){
            for (T *animal : animals){
                 delete animal;
            }
            animals.clear();
        }

    public :
        ~House(){
            clearList(dogs);
            clearList(cats);
        }
};
```

If you really want to use polymorphism for the function, then you would have to change the `vector` objects to be the same type, then you don't need the template, eg:

```
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual ~Animal(){}
};

class Dog : public Animal{};
class Cat : public Animal{};

class House{
    private :
        std::vector<Animal*> Dogs;
        std::vector<Animal*> Cats;

        void clearList(std::vector<Animal*> &animals){
            for (Animal *animal : animals){
                 delete animal;
            }
            animals.clear();
        }

    public :
        ~House(){
            clearList(dogs);
            clearList(cats);
        }
};
```

Otherwise, simply do not store pointers to begin with, and let `vector`'s own destructor destroy the objects for you:

```
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual ~Animal(){}
};

class Dog : public Animal{};
class Cat : public Animal{};

class House{
    private :
        std::vector<Dog> Dogs;
        std::vector<Cat> Cats;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it with polymorphism with a few small changes to the program. Templates are a little more advanced.

Comment: That's a little more detail than I wanted to give for what smells like a homework question. Nice of you to point out the solution that doesn't use pointers though.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It seems to work just like I wanted. Not sure my programming teacher will like it, but i'll try anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

To effectively use polymorphism, you need two things: virtual functions, and pointers or references to the base class. In your case, since you already have pointers, just make them pointers to the base class rather than the derived class. And since you want to delete these pointers, make the destructors virtual.

Comment: "*since you already have pointers, just make them pointers to the base class rather than the derived class*" - yes, but then you will likely have to type-cast them every time you want to access them.

Comment: @GRC no, because your code is only about 1/3 of what's necessary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if all the methods you wanted to use on those objects were also virtual, you wouldn't need any casting. Hard to know from this toy example if that will be a problem or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do appreciate your comment but I do want to know what am I missing. :)

Comment: @GRC: `vector<Animal*>`, `vector<Dog*>`, and `vector<Cat*>` are three distinct types, despite being based on the same `vector<T>` implementation. You can't interchange them like you are thinking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are confusing the hell out of me now :(. You are doing the same thing :) `void clearList(std::vector<Animal*> &animals)`. This is copied from your code :)

Comment: @GRC Look at that particular example again more carefully, I had changed everything in it to use just `vector<Animal*>` everywhere, so there is only 1 type involved. My other examples distinguish `vector<Dog*>` from `vector<Cat*>` - 2 distinct types